# QuerySelectorAll - returns null

Tags: html, excel, vba

I'm having a weird problem with Excel build version and a macro.
Basically, the macro reads a html page and does a queryselectorAll for a specific table ID and tag.
The code runs smooth as butter on my machine and for other users.
We all have version 16.0 (Office 365) and build 13801 (from application.version and application.build).
The user for which the macro doesn't work has the build 14326.

Does anything change between the 2 different build version ? I'm confused ...

The error is generated by the object `inputBoxes` that remains Null.

All the users are printing the line `Debug.Print html.body.innerHTML` just fine.

I've tried with a different selector `html.querySelectorAll("td")` but the error remains the same.

The macro goes :

```
Public Sub getGDIN(cp12 As String, adl As Integer, frm As UserForm)

    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim response As String

    With http
        .Open "GET", "http://me.intra-dmu-13/gdi.asp?Type=P&cp12=" & cp12, False
        .send
    
        If .Status <> 200 Then
            MsgBox "Unable to load the requested page (GDI)", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
    
        response = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

    html.body.innerHTML = response

    Dim inputBoxes As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ctrl As Control

    Set inputBoxes = html.querySelectorAll("#Table3 td")
    'Set inputBoxes2 = html.querySelectorAll("td") <--- same error

    Debug.Print html.body.innerHTML ' <--- print the whole html (both build version)

    If inputBoxes.Length < 32 Then ' <--- ERROR NULL
        MsgBox "Nothing has been found with this file number.", vbInformation
        frm.btnGenerer.Enabled = False
    
        For Each ctrl In frm.Controls
            If ctrl.Name Like "tb*adl" & adl And Not ctrl.Name = "tbCp12_adl" & adl Then
                ctrl = vbNullString
            End If
        Next ctrl
        Exit Sub
    End If

' ...

End Sub
```

In addition, here is the generated html (since it's from an Intranet) :

```
<TABLE id=Table3 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%" border=0>
  <TBODY>
    <TR height=10>
      <TD class=cell-login height=10><IMG border=0 alt="" src="about:../../Images/Spacer.gif" width=1 height=10></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD class=cell-login>
        <TABLE style="FONT: 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" cellSpacing=2 cellPadding=2 border=0>
          <TBODY>
            <TR>
                <TD><B>CP-12</B></TD>
                <TD>:</TD>
                <TD>BBBB01018097<INPUT type=hidden value=BBBB01018097 name=CP12></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD><B>Nom</B></TD>
                <TD>:</TD>
                <TD>Byer<INPUT type=hidden value=Byer name=Nom></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD><B>Prenom</B></TD>
                <TD>:</TD>
                <TD>Joe<INPUT type=hidden value=Joe name=Prenom></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD><B>Titre</B></TD>
                <TD>:</TD>
                <TD>monsieur<INPUT type=hidden value=monsieur name=Sexe></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD><B>Date of birth</B></TD>
                <TD>:</TD>
                <TD>1980-01-01<INPUT type=hidden value=1980-01-01 name=DB></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD><B>SIN</B></TD>
                <TD>:</TD>
                <TD>121-111-111<INPUT type=hidden value=121-111-111 name=SIN></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD><B>Langue</B></TD>
                <TD>:</TD>
                <TD>Anglais<INPUT type=hidden value=Anglais name=Langue></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                 <TD><B>Adresse</B></TD>
                 <TD>: </TD>
                 <TD>9999, CH DE LA COTE-SAINT-LUC APP.9
                      <BR>MONTREAL (QUEBEC) H1X 7B8 
                      <INPUT type=hidden value="9999, CH DE LA COTE-SAINT-LUC APP.9" name=Adresse> 
                      <INPUT type=hidden value=MONTREAL name=Ville> 
                      <INPUT type=hidden value="H1X 7B8" name=CP> 
                  </TD>
             </TR>
             <TR>
                  <TD><B>Telephone</B></TD>
                  <TD>:</TD>
                  <TD>(000) 000-0000<INPUT type=hidden value="(000) 000-0000" name=Telephone></TD>
             </TR>
             <!--
             <TR>
                 <TD colspan=3 align=center><img src="../../Images/fleche-connect.gif" alt="" align="absmiddle" border="0">&nbsp;<a class="lien" href="javascript:AncAdr('BYEJ09027497');">Plus...</a></TD>
             </TR>
             -->
           </TBODY>
         </TABLE>
        </TD>
      </TR>
    </FORM>
  </TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

The variable `cp12` passed into the sub in simply a string that contains a file number to query our ministry database.

If anyone can shed some light ... or maybe suggest a different approach.

Thank you.

Comment: Need some sample inputs which should produce the results you expect in the response

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for your reply. I don't know what you mean by "Need some sample inputs". The macro runned just fine until the newest build installed by our IT team a few days ago. I'm stuck with a variable (inputBoxes) that remains NULL after being initialized.

Comment: for example what gets passed to `cp12` which would be expected to produce hits for the request?  Or is that URL not publicly accessible for testing?

Comment: @TimWilliams I've updated my question with the HTML code generated by the web server. The variable cp12 is just a string that contains a file number to query our database. (I'm not the author is the html coding ... don't jugde it haha)

Comment: I'm not sure there's any way for us to debug this without any access to the URL, particularly if it's only not working on one PC.  `querySelectorAll("td")` *should* work given that HTML.

Comment: To be more precise, it's not working for the users that have Excel (365) build 14326. And I know for a fact that the code is working just fine. That's the main reason why I asked here with all the knowledgeable and experienced users. That maybe I missed something between the 2 different build. Thanks Tim  :)

Comment: Odd since the objects you're automating and which seem to be the root of the problem are not part of the Excel application...

Comment: You might have just gave me a hint. I'll look into this. I'll let this question opened and try to figure out what's wrong. Thanks for your time.  :)

Comment: It is the newer builds at fault I suspect. I believe the issue to affect at least one of the interfaces when using late bound object to hold a reference to DispStaticNodeList. Use a `With` block to hold the reference rather than assigning to a variable or add the `MSHTML.HTMLDocument` library and declare as `Dim inputBoxes as MSHTML.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection`

Comment: @QHarr I will give it a try. I found this article that explains it. Thanks a million to point that out!  https://techinplanet.com/how-to-hold-a-reference-to-the-items-matched-by-queryselectorall-in-a-variable-that-allows-you-to-access-its-methods/

Comment: @QHarr, you were right. I made the changes and it's working again. You are a life saver.